# Python DataFrame : Get count from a dataframe column based on condition?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

```
            name              status
    0       alex                pass
    1       alex                pass
    2       alex                unknown
    3       marcus              pass
    4       marcus              fail
    5       anthony             fail
    6       paul                pass
    7       paul                unknown
    8       paul                fail
    9       paul                pass
```

if one the `name` column record has `status = pass`. I'm trying get count of `status = pass`

```
            name            count      
    0       alex              2   
    1       marcus            1     
    2       anthony           0       
    3       paul              2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate `sum` of boolean mask, because `True`s are processing like `1`:

```
df = df['status'].eq('pass').groupby(df['name']).sum().reset_index(name='count')
print (df)
      name  count
0     alex      2
1  anthony      0
2   marcus      1
3     paul      2
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) and index on the column of interest:

```
pd.crosstab(df.name, df.status)['pass'].reset_index()

      name  pass
0     alex     2
1  anthony     0
2   marcus     1
3     paul     2
```